# How to serialize abstract base models and sub-models in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, abstract-class, django-serializer

I have a model `Complaint` which can have many `Evidence`s.
An `Evidence` can be an `Attachment` or a `Link` and is an [abstract base model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes-1).

```py
from django.db import models


class Complaint(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()


class Evidence(models.Model):
    complaint = models.ForeignKey(
        Complaint,
        related_name='%(class)s_evidences',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    is_attached = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Attachment(Evidence):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='attachments')


class Link(Evidence):
    url = models.URLField()
```

I want to be able take input of a `Complaint` and and all its `Evidence`s from a single view like so:

```json
{
    "text": "Lorem ipsum",
    "evidences": [
        {
            "description": "dolor sit amet",
            "is_attached": false,
            "url": "https://example.com"
        },
        {
            "description": "consectetur adipisicing elit",
            "is_attached": true,
            "file": "http://localhost:8000/media/attachments/filename"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I have in my `serializers.py` thus far:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Complaint, Evidence, Attachment, Link


class EvidenceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):  # since ModelSerializer can not be used with abstract models
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    is_attached = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        model = Evidence
        fields = ['id', 'is_attached']


class AttachmentSerializer(EvidenceSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = EvidenceSerializer.Meta.fields + ['file']


class LinkSerializer(EvidenceSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = EvidenceSerializer.Meta.fields + ['url']


class ComplaintSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    evidences = EvidenceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Complaint
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'evidences']
```

This gives the following error when requesting to the complaint POST view (`/lodge`):

```
TypeError at /lodge
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Complaint.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Complaint.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ComplaintSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

Bottom of the traceback:

```
TypeError: Complaint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'evidences'
```

**How should I write the serializers for these models?**

The error message says to override `Complaint.objects.create`, but I don’t know how to go about it.
I tried following the example given for [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) in the official docs, but it does not use abstract models.